# Strong induction problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $s_1,s_2, s_3,\ldots $ be the sequence defined by $s_1 = 1, s_2 =8$ and $ s_k = s_{k-1} + 2s_{k-2}$ for all natural numbers $k > 3$. Prove $s_n=3\cdot 2^{n-1} + 2(-1)^n $.

I did most of the work; I just don't know how to do the remaining algebra of the problem.

$s_1 = 3 \cdot2^0+2(-1)^1 = 1 $

$s_2 = 3 \cdot 2^1+2(-1)^2 = 8 $

Assume that $ s_k =3\cdot 2^{k-1} +2(-1)^k$

Prove $ s_{k+1} = 3\cdot 2^k+2(-1)^{k+1} $

$s_{k-1} = 3\cdot2^{k-2} + 2(-1)^{k-1}$

So then I plugged in the values for $s_{k+1} =s_k + 2s_{k-1}$

$$ s_{k+1}= \big(3\cdot 2^{k-1} +2(-1)^k\big) + 2\big(3\cdot 2^{k-2} + 2(-1)^{k-1}\big) $$

Answer (score 4):

$$\begin{align*}
s_{k+1} &= \big(3\cdot2^{k-1} +2(-1)^{k}\big) + 2\big(3\cdot2^{k-2} + 2(-1)^{k-1}\big)\\
&=3\cdot2^{k-1}+2(-1)^k+3\cdot2^{k-1}+4(-1)^{k-1}\\
&=3(2^{k-1}+2^{k-1})+2\big((-1)^k+2(-1)^{k-1}\big)\\
&=3(2^{k-1}+2^{k-1})+2\big((-1)^k-2(-1)^{k}\big)\\
&=3\cdot2\cdot2^{k-1}+2\cdot(-1)\cdot(-1)^k\\
&=3\cdot2^k+2\cdot(-1)^{k+1}
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 1):

The characteristic equation of the recurrence relation $s_k = s_{k-1} + 2s_{k-2}$ is $\lambda^2 - \lambda - 2 = 0$. The roots are $2, -1$. Hence $s_n = A2^n + B(-1)^n$. Using $s_1 = 1, s_2 = 8$, we get $A=\dfrac{3}{2}, B= 2$. Thus $s_n = 3\cdot 2^{n-1} + 2(-1)^n$.

This is shorter unless the exercise requires the use of induction!